Create tables and apply migration on Flask app startup
I am working on a flask app and I want to be sure that when my service runs it will have created the database it need based on its SQLAlchemy models if it doesnt exists and apply all migration if needed. I saw somewhere that i can do in with an initialization method which I call on startup up something like :
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

# Create core services as singletons
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
jwt = JWTManager()

def init_app(app: Flask):
    # Initialize database with the app
    db.init_app(app)

    # Initialize Flask-Migrate with the app and db
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    # Initialize Flask-JWT-Extended with the app
    jwt.init_app(app)

    # Create the database tables if they dont exist
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        migrate.upgrade()

but the upgrade() method seems to not exist for the migrate object I get this error:

'Migrate' object has no attribute 'upgrade'

how can I achieve this?
